# The range of non-identically distributed binomial variables

Tags: distributions, random-variable, approximation

Lets say we have three independent variables:
$$\eqalign{
X_{1}\sim &B(n,\frac{1}{2}+\beta) \cr 
X_{2}\sim &B(n,\frac{1}{2}) \cr
X_{3}\sim &B(n,\frac{1}{2}-\beta).
}$$

I'm looking for the distribution of

$$\max(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})-\min(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}).$$

For sufficiently large $n$ we have

$$\Pr(\max(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})=k)\approx \Pr(X_{1}=k)$$

and similarly

$$\Pr(\min(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})=k)\approx \Pr(X_{3}=k).$$

So using those two we have:

$$\eqalign{
&\Pr(\max(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})-\min(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})=k) \cr
&\approx \Pr(X_{1}-X_{3}=k) \cr
&=(\frac{1}{2}+\beta)^k  (\frac{1}{2}-\beta)^{2n+k}\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{i-k} \left(\frac{1+2\beta}{1-2\beta} \right)^{2i}
}$$

but this doesn't seem to be easy to approximate...

I was thinking about another approach. Binomial variables can be approximated by normal distributions and the sum of normally distributed variables is well known, so it would be easy to calculate.

**The question**: Are there any inequalities that could give a better approximation? I'm aware only of the Chernoff bound but it is not very helpful here.

Comment: The quality of an approximation tends to depend on the values of the parameters.  Can you stipulate anything about the values of $n$ or $\beta$ that you are interested in?  For example, how small can $n$ be?  How close to $1/2$ can $\beta$ be?

Comment: @Whuber: It can be assumed that $\beta$ is far from $\frac{1}{2}$ lets say $\beta \approx 0.1$. Case when n is big is simple, so I'm more interested in case where n is rather small: $10 \le n \le 20$

Comment: Just for clarification (because it came up as a question in some comments), I take it that your allusion to the normal approximation should be interpreted to mean we can approximate each $X_i$ with a normal variable and perform the integrations to estimate the distribution of the range.  (Note that this is *not* the same as a "sum" of normal distributions, nor is it easy to calculate.)  Is this what you were thinking of, or have I misinterpreted your idea?

Comment: @whuber: To be honest I was considering both versions, but the one that I wrote about was different from what you proposed. $X_{1}$ and $X_{3}$ can be approximated using normal distribution and then we just approximate the range by the $X_{1}-X_{3}$ which have normal distribution. It works quite well for big n. Your method gives better results, but it is much harder to calculate.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Yes, when $n$ is large, the problem is an easy exercise, because you can be practically certain the range equals $X_1 - X_3$.  Thus the challenge is to compute the distribution when there's an appreciable chance that $X_2$ will exceed $X_1$ or be less than $X_3$.  This happens when $2\beta^2n/(1-2\beta^2)$ is less than 6 or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n \le 20$ just compute the distribution by brute force.

For example, with $n=3$ the pdf is

$$\begin{array}{}
 k=0: &-\frac{7}{64} \left(-1+4 \beta ^2\right)^3 \cr
 k=1: &\frac{39}{256} \left(1-4 \beta ^2\right)^2 \left(3+4 \beta ^2\right) \cr 
 k=2: &-\frac{3}{128} \left(-15-92 \beta ^2+560 \beta ^4+192 \beta ^6\right) \cr 
 k=3: &\frac{1}{256} \left(21+564 \beta ^2+1392 \beta ^4+448 \beta ^6\right)
\end{array}$$

This was produced by the Mathematica code

```
Clear[f, i, q];
f[n_, p_, k_] := Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k);
i[k1_, k2_, k3_, k_] := If[Max[{k1, k2, k3}] - Min[{k1, k2, k3}] == k, 1, 0];
q[n_, k_, p_] := 
  Sum[f[n, 1/2 + p, k1] f[n, 1/2, k2] f[n, 1/2 - p, k3] 
     i[k1, k2, k3, k], {k1, 0, n}, {k2, Max[0, k1 - k], Min[n, k1 + k]}, 
     {k3, Max[0, k1 - k, k2 - k], Min[n, k1 + k, k2 + k]}];
With[{n=3}, Table[q[n, k, \[Beta]], {k,0,n}]]
```

Calculations of the entire distribution for $n=20$ take four seconds.  Here are plots for $\beta = 0, 1/6, 1/3$.  (As $\beta$ increases, the distribution shifts to the right.)

[image]

Comment: Calculating this by brute force is deffinitely a solution, but I wanted to avoid, but if there is no better idea I will use it. Thanks for the code, it will save me some of the work.

Comment: @Tomek For $n \lt 10$ we can't hope to find good approximations.  Given that the brute force computation is easy to code and executes fairly quickly, the main reason for looking for *any* approximations would be to improve our understanding of the behavior of the sample range.  If that's your situation, the sum in your question can be reduced to a case of the hypergeometric function.  That's a trivial result but it suggests analytical ways of studying the range and creating approximations.

Answer (score 3):

Call $R_n=\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)-\min(X_1,X_2,X_3)$. The usual LLN shows that $R_n/n$ converges to $2\beta$ almost surely and in $L^1$. (The **distribution** of $R_n$ for a given fixed $n$ is an altogether different story.)

Comment: @Didier Piau: I'm looking for the distribution of $R_{n}$ for fixed n, but I would be also satisfied with first two moments. When n approaches infinity it is easy to calculate them.

Comment: @Tomek: "to calculate them" in the sense of "to compute some simple asymptotic equivalents of them", I presume.

Comment: @Didier Piau: Yes, of course I meant to calculate asymptotic equivalent.

Comment: @Tomek: then the asymptotic equivalents you are interested in are $2\beta n$ for the expectation of $R_n$ and $2n(\frac14 -\beta^2)$ for its variance.

Comment: @Didier Comparisons with the examples I posted for $n=20$ show we'll need much larger $n$ before these approximations are reasonably close.  Note, too, that for extreme values of $\beta$ (including near $0$), the distribution tends to be quite skewed, implying that more than the expectation and variance are needed for decent characterization.  Until $n$ gets huge, then, @Tomek's suggestion to use Normal approximations looks more worthwhile.

Comment: @whuber: thanks for your comment. Why do you write that the linear approximations of the expectation and variance are not "reasonably close" to the actual values? I see nothing about this in your post, so... did you compute these values and choose not to post them? About the last sentence of your comment: the equivalent of the variance I wrote in my last comment is precisely a consequence of the normal approximation you advocate.

Comment: @Didier Good questions. (1) $2\beta n$ in my examples equals about 0, 6.7, and 13.3.  The distributions have modes at 4, 8, and 15, respectively.  Especially in the case $\beta=0$ the approximation is pretty far off (more than 1 SD wrong).  (2) The normal approximation @Tomek proposes differs from yours: one approximates each of the $X_i$ with a Gaussian and from that does the integration to estimate the distribution of the range.  The result is decidedly non-normal yet, when $(1/2-\beta)n \ge 5$ or so, should work quite well with a continuity correction.

Comment: @Didier I did a calculation to check @Tomek's normal approximation for $n=20, \beta=1/3$.  It qualitatively reproduces the pdf.  The errors in the pdf are usually less than 0.01 and the error in the cdf has a max of about 0.02 at $k=14$.  We can expect better performance for $\beta$ closer to $0$ and worse performance for smaller $n$.  The numerical integration, which takes some effort, will become computationally more efficient than exact calculation somewhere around $n=50$ I guess.

Comment: @whuber: Three comments. First, about "Tomek's normal approximation": to what post/comment are you referring? Once again, the asymptotic variance $2n(\frac14-\beta^2)$ follows from a **normal** approximation. Second, when $\beta>0$, did you compare $2\beta n$ and the **expectations** (not the **modes**) of your simulations? Third, when $\beta=0$, $R_n$ is of order $\sqrt{n}$ and $2R_n/\sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution to a non degenenerate positive random variable $\max(N_1,N_2,N_3)-\min(N_1,N_2,N_3)$ with $(N_i)$ i.i.d. standard normal.

Comment: @Didier (1) The original question.  (2) Look at the plot in my response.  The expectation for $\beta=0$ is larger than the mode; the expectations for the other values are close to the modes.  (3) Fine.  But "convergence" tells us what happens for arbitrarily large $n$.  Without additional information it tells us *nothing* about particular values of $n$.  When we turn to the actual distributions, it's clear the asymptotic estimates are not very good even for small $\beta$ and $n=20$ and it's also apparent the distributions are not approximately normal for $\beta$ near $0$ or near $1/2$.